# PostgreSQL информация о системе (OS)

Tags: sql, база-данных, postgresql

Как я могу в PostgreSQL получить системную информацию? например названия и размер дисков, в MySQL  есть таблицы как `sys.dm_os_sys_info`, `sys.master_files` и т.д. 
Есть ли аналогичное в Postgres? данные нужно получать через SQL запрос

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PostgreSQL не считает необходимым получать и предоставлять на уровне SQL лишние данные о системе. Для сложной СУБД поддерживающей работу на внушительном зоопарке разных операционных систем это потребует порядком дополнительного кода, который требуется написать, отладить, протестировать, затем поддерживать актуальность и исправлять баги (как самого этого кода, так и обходить баги получения этих данных в самих операционных системах). Ради весьма и весьма узкого прикладного использования.

Однако вы можете вызвать любое приложение ОС с помощью запроса [`COPY FROM PROGRAM`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html).

```
create temp table stdout_lines (line text);
copy stdout_lines from program 'lscpu';
table stdout_lines ;
```

Любо использовать любой из языков функций, которые позволяют вызывать внешние программы. Например, с помощью хранимой функции `pl/perlu` или `pl/python`

Так же есть несколько штатных функций [по работе с файлами](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-ADMIN-GENFILE).

Все эти способы в общем случае ограничены в использовании суперпользователем.